# Is a flat scatter plot no correlation?

Tags: statistics

is A "no correlation or zero correlation?"
if so, does A have more information than B despite both showing no correlation? Because here no correlation on A means you can still predict that if you increase X, Y will stay the same.

A)
[image: A]

B) [image: B]

Comment: Difficult to say for sure, given the small image and the unfortunate scale of the vertical axis, but I think I see a slight uptrend in the data. If so, the correlation could not be 0.// What is the purpose of graph (B)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not confuse slope with correlation.

Below I use R to generate data with a strong positive correlation between $X$ and $Y,$ and with a graph that looks somewhat like your (A).

```
set.seed(828)  # for reproducibility 
x = runif(20)
y = 10 + 3*x + rnorm(20,0,.5)
plot(x,y, ylim=c(0,30), pch=20)
cor(x,y)
[1] 0.8411499
```

[image]

Correlation has no units, so you should not expect
a highly positive correlation to give the appearance of a highly positive slope on a graph.

Here is another plot of exactly the same data in which the
slope *appears* to be greater because of the vertical scale used.

[image]

Comment: so if my data fits the line y=c for some constant c, then the correlation, r, can still be r ≈ 1?

Comment: As long as the slope of the line isn't $0$ or $\infty,$ in which cases $r$ isn't defined because one of the standard deviations in its denominator would be $0.$

Comment: if r (Pearson's correlation) isn't defined, is there any conclusion to be made about some form of correlation? because I am aware that r ≈ 0 just tells us that there is no LINEAR correlation. I can still be correlated by other means such as quadratically (Spearman's correlation)

Comment: If slope is exactly 0, then changes in x are not accompanied by changes in y.  Informally, you might say there is no association. But $r$ is undefined. Correlation is only one way to quantify association.